# Show Category Thumb Image on startpage

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cms, category, image

How can I show the thumb image from a category on the shops home page?

I added a [getThumbnailUrl](http://www.douglasradburn.co.uk/getting-category-thumbnail-images-with-magento/) function in `app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Model\category.php` but I don't know how to call it with [CMS Directives](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/cms/markup_tags).

I would like to display some categories as a grid. As a work-a-round I hard coded the link to the thumb but that will be broken if a new thumb is uploaded:

```
    <li class="span4">
        <a class="banner banner1" href="{{store url='new.html'}}">
            <img src="{{media url='catalog/category/new-thumb.jpg'}}" alt="New Stuff"  />
        </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to do. Are you trying to show a grid/list with several categories on the homepage?

Comment: @SanderMangel yes, that what I am doing. I made an update with some html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no (easy) way to do this dynamically from the CMS page content editor. I'm afraid this will require some custom code.

Best course of action would be to create a new extensions, let's call it Acme_Categorygrid for this example. For more info about creating extensions please view this comment by [chapagain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5594920)

In your etc/config.xml file add the following code

```
<config>
    [...]
    <global>
            [...]
        <blocks>
            <categorygrid>
                <class>Acme_Categorygrid_Block</class>
            </categorygrid>
        </blocks>
            [...]
    </global>
    [...]
</config>
```

Then create a new Block class with the following code

```
class Acme_Categorygrid_Block_Grid extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    public function categories()
    {
        $parent_id = 1;

        $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($parent_id);

        return $children;
    }
}
```

Now all we need is a template file

```
<?php

$categories = $this->categories();

?>
<ul class="category-grid">
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl();?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $category->getThumbnail();?>" alt="<?php echo $category->getName();?>"/>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Now you can add in the content of the CMS page a block tag: `{{block type='categorygrid/grid' template='categorygrid/grid.phtml'}}`

This should now display the just created block. Mind you, I haven't tested the code so it might need some tweaking, especially in the template file but hopefully this'll help you a long way.

Comment: What is the name of the template file and where do you put it?

Comment: the name is `grid.phtml`, you can put it under `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/templates/categorygrid`